# setContentView with layout containing a MapView very slow the first time

Tags: android, android-mapview

calling `setContentView` with layout containing a MapView is very slow the first time, and quite fast afterwards. Why? Does it already load some map images called? How can I make it faster (I'm in debug mode, just in case...)?

Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    

    setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutwithmapview);   //very slow the first time

    //...
}
```

Comment: Can you show your layout?  What is your setup?  Running in the emulator?

Comment: I'm running in debug mode in my Samsung Galaxy S. I edited the question to show the layout.

Comment: I removed my layout because it also happen with simple layout with only a mapview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve that I added a MapView (not used) in a layout shown after my splash screen, so that the first long call of setContentView is not noticed.